# Как поднять postgres в docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

С докером, скажу сразу, не работал.

Postgres не поднимается, в чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Или выводит вот такое если из пути var/lib убрать, но базы всёравно нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдаёт вот такой лог.

```
2023-07-18 19:28:43 
2023-07-18 19:28:43 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2023-07-18 19:28:43 
2023-07-18 19:28:43 
2023-07-18 14:28:43.242 UTC [1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/data/postgres" has invalid permissions
2023-07-18 19:28:43 
2023-07-18 14:28:43.242 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
```

Проблема конкретно с этим.
Что здесь не так?

```
postgres:
        container_name: postgres
        image: postgres:13.3
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 5s
          retries: 5
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: db
          POSTGRES_USER: user
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          PGDATA: /var/lib/data/postgres
        volumes:
           - ../fituro_data/postgres:/var/lib/data/postgres
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        networks:
          - postgres-network
```

докер файл - [docker-composer.yml](https://pastebin.com/AT8YbAKH)

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо установить правильные разрешения для папки

```bash
sudo chmod 700 -R /var/lib/data/postgres
```

См. https://github.com/ClusterHQ/dvol/issues/45#issuecomment-370995983

Второй способ - создание [внешнего тома](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1459280/363118).